words ending with an accentuated char JS
To find the words ending with an accentuated char and log them.
I thought this could do it.


const text = 'aztec, résumé, façade, and azure';
const words = text.match(/\b\w*[éèêëáàâäíìîïóòôöúùûüç]\b/g);
console.log(words);



`
But all I get is > ré,faç

Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/280712/how-can-i-use-unicode-aware-regular-expressions-in-javascript

Have you read about what the .match() function does?

Have you forgotten about šžčć (and the too many others) - or your list contains exactly the only ones you're interested in?

/\b\p{L}*[éèêëáàâäíìîïóòôöúùûüç]+\p{L}*\b/ug

\b will not work since it will also treat accented characters as a \b.
Instead you could use the u (unicode) flag, and before your list of accented characters use \p{L} and in the end check if followed by a non word character or end of line: Regex.101 example


const text = 'aztec, résumé, façade, and azure, mardí';
const words = text.match(/\p{L}*[éèêëáàâäíìîïóòôöúùûüç](?=\W|$)/ug);
console.log(words);



